# Open cover with xUnit tests for azure function

Tags: code-coverage, opencover

I have a project that contains implementation of azure functions. I have created unit tests using xUnit for this as another project under the same solution. I have added a powershell script at solution level to run opencover exe. But the script is giving error as "OpenCover.Console.exe : The specified framework version '2.0' could not be parsed". How can I use open cover to get the code coverage for the same. My folder structure is

```
--PM(folder)
  --PM.sln
  --PM(folder)
  --PMTests(folder)
  --TestsAndCoverage.ps1
```

My TestsAndCoverage.ps1 has the below content.

```
$testProjects = "PMTests"

# Get the most recent OpenCover NuGet package from the dotnet nuget packages
$nugetOpenCoverPackage = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "\.nuget\packages\OpenCover"
$latestOpenCover = Join-Path -Path ((Get-ChildItem -Path $nugetOpenCoverPackage | Sort-Object Fullname -Descending)[0].FullName) -ChildPath "tools\OpenCover.Console.exe"
# Get the most recent OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter from the dotnet nuget packages
$nugetCoberturaConverterPackage = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "\.nuget\packages\OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter"
$latestCoberturaConverter = Join-Path -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path                 
$nugetCoberturaConverterPackage | Sort-Object Fullname -Descending)[0].FullName -ChildPath "tools\OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter.exe"

If (Test-Path "$PSScriptRoot\OpenCover.coverageresults"){
Remove-Item "$PSScriptRoot\OpenCover.coverageresults"
}

If (Test-Path "$PSScriptRoot\Cobertura.coverageresults"){
Remove-Item "$PSScriptRoot\Cobertura.coverageresults"
}

& dotnet restore

$testRuns = 1;
foreach ($testProject in $testProjects){
# Arguments for running dotnet
$dotnetArguments = "xunit", "-xml `"`"$PSScriptRoot\testRuns_$testRuns.testresults`"`""

"Running tests with OpenCover"
& $latestOpenCover `
    -register:user `
    -target:dotnet.exe `
    -targetdir:$PSScriptRoot\$testProject `
    "-targetargs:$dotnetArguments" `
    -returntargetcode `
    -output:"$PSScriptRoot\OpenCover.coverageresults" `
    -mergeoutput `
    -oldStyle `
    -excludebyattribute:System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute `
    "-filter:+[Sample*]* -[*.Tests]* -[*.Tests.*]*"

    $testRuns++
}

"Converting coverage reports to Cobertura format"
& $latestCoberturaConverter `
-input:"$PSScriptRoot\OpenCover.coverageresults" `
-output:"$PSScriptRoot\Cobertura.coverageresults" `
"-sources:$PSScriptRoot"
```